# Docker pull certificate signed by unknown authority error

Tags: docker

When I run

```
docker pull mysql
```

this error shows up.

```
error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I am running docker in wsl

How can I rectify this problem?